# Problem with react store and redux - shows properly but editing cause error

Tags: reactjs, json, react-redux, store

I am creating react app based on store and react redux which fetch data from json file. And I have a problem, I created all structure and it's showing properly but when I try to edit some data it shows me error: state.properties.map is not a function
I don't have full understanding how store and redux exactly work, thats why I need your help to find where is a problem, could you help me?

Reducer:

```
import { UPDATE_PROPERTY } from "./actions";
import data from "./data.json"; // Importuj dane z pliku data.json

const initialState = {
  properties: data, // Ustaw dane z data.json jako początkowy stan properties
};

const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_PROPERTY:
      const updatedProperties = state.properties.map((prop) =>
        prop.name === action.payload.name ? action.payload : prop
      );
      return { ...state, properties: updatedProperties };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default rootReducer;
```

Store:

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import rootReducer from "./reducers";

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    data: rootReducer,
  },
});

export default store;
```

Actions:

```
export const UPDATE_PROPERTY = 'UPDATE_PROPERTY';

export const updateProperty = (property) => ({
  type: UPDATE_PROPERTY,
  payload: property,
});
```

Index.js:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "./store";
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Property:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Checkbox from "@material-ui/core/Checkbox";
import FormControlLabel from "@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel";
import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";

import { updateProperty } from "./actions";

const Property = ({ property }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [editedProperty, setEditedProperty] = useState(property);

  const handleBlur = () => {
    dispatch(updateProperty(editedProperty));
  };

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value, type, checked } = event.target;
    const newValue = type === "checkbox" ? checked : value;

    setEditedProperty({
      ...editedProperty,
      [name]: newValue,
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>{property.name}</h3>
      {property.type === "text" && (
        <TextField
          name="value"
          value={editedProperty.value}
          onBlur={handleBlur}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      )}
      {property.type === "checkbox" && (
        <FormControlLabel
          control={
            <Checkbox
              name="value"
              checked={editedProperty.value}
              onBlur={handleBlur}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          }
          label="Check"
        />
      )}
      {property.type === "combobox" && (
        <Autocomplete
          options={property.options}
          name="value"
          value={editedProperty.value}
          onBlur={handleBlur}
          onChange={(event, newValue) => {
            handleChange({ target: { name: "value", value: newValue } });
          }}
          freeSolo
          renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Property;
```

App:

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import Property from "./Property";
import Accordion from "@mui/material/Accordion";
import AccordionSummary from "@mui/material/AccordionSummary";
import AccordionDetails from "@mui/material/AccordionDetails";
 function App() {
  const properties = useSelector((state) => state.data.properties);

  const groupedProperties = {};

  properties.properties.forEach((property) => {
    if (!groupedProperties[property.group]) {
      groupedProperties[property.group] = [];
    }
    groupedProperties[property.group].push(property);
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {Object.entries(groupedProperties).map(([groupName, groupProperties]) => (
        <Accordion key={groupName}>
          <AccordionSummary>{groupName}</AccordionSummary>
          <AccordionDetails>
            <div>
              {groupProperties.map((property) => (
                <Property key={property.name} property={property} />
              ))}
            </div>
          </AccordionDetails>
        </Accordion>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Thats all components I use, If you see (as propably will be) some bad practice I do or stupid solutions - I will be grateful if you point them out.

Comment: `import data from "./data.json";` - What is the *value* of `data` here? It seems it is not an array as you and the code assume. Please [edit] to clarify and to make for a more complete [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

By default properties is undefined. .map cannot work with undefined.

Try to use this

```js
const updatedProperties = state.properties ? state.properties.map((prop) =>
  prop.name === action.payload.name ? action.payload : prop
) : [];
```

Comment: I did try this but I still got the same error

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code in the `App` component

```js
const properties = useSelector((state) => state.data.properties);

const groupedProperties = {};

properties.properties.forEach((property) => {
  if (!groupedProperties[property.group]) {
    groupedProperties[property.group] = [];
  }
  groupedProperties[property.group].push(property);
});
```

It would appear that the `state.data.properties` value is actually an object with a `properties` property that is an array. In other words, `properties.properties` is the array.

Update the `rootReducer` to access `data.properties` array

```
const initialState = {
  properties: data.properties,
};
```

or to pass the *entire* `data` object reference *as* the `initialState` value.

```js
const initialState = data;
```

Example:

```js
import { UPDATE_PROPERTY } from "./actions";
import data from "./data.json";

const initialState = {
  properties: data.properties,
};
// Or
// const initialState = data;

const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  const { type, payload } = action;

  switch (type) {
    case UPDATE_PROPERTY:
      return {
        ...state,
        properties: state.properties.map((prop) =>
          prop.name === payload.name ? payload : prop
        )
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default rootReducer;
```